# Python Error : cannot import name scanner

Tags: python, python-2.7

System : XP, work with python 2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import json
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\json\__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from .decoder import JSONDecoder
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\json\decoder.py", line 7, in <module>
    from json import scanner
ImportError: cannot import name scanner
```

Anyone can explain me how to manage this error please ???

this morning I haven't got this problem, but this afternoon my script won't work ((

Comment: What does `import json; print json.__file__` print?

Comment: thank's for answer.
in idle when i does import json i have this error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import json
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\json\__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from .decoder import JSONDecoder
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\json\decoder.py", line 7, in <module>
    from json import scanner
ImportError: cannot import name scanner
and when i does print json.__file__ i have this error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
print json.__file__
name 'json' is not defined

Comment: Hrm, looks like ArcGIS is a weird beast; all I can do is take stabs at guessing. It *looks* as if `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\json\scanner.py` is missing (which is present in a default Python setup).

Comment: just guessing, are you running that import json in the C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\ directory?

Comment: Can you verify that the file `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\json\scanner.py` exists?

Comment: he exist in folder ArcGIS, yes.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is caused by relative import path,

File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\json\decoder.py", line 7,
    from json import scanner

it's trying to import scanner from
    C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\json

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is. And that *works* in Python 2.7. Just not for the OP, and **that is why there is a question**. Your answer does not solve the problem, it just... tells the OP that it should work but doesn't?

Comment: just guessing, are you running that `import json` in the C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\ directory?

Comment: Ask the OP, not me. :-P Post this comment on the question.

Comment: Not that that would matter. The OP did `import json` which correctly imported `lib/json/__init__.py`; why then does `from .decoder import JSONDecoder` work correctly but `from json import scanner` not? `json` in that last statement *must* be the `lib/json/` module because the `json` module does not change the path. Most likely `lib/json/scanner.py` **is not there**.

Comment: when i use the IDLE to execute import json in this folder on the lib , that's work. but when i use idle in others folders tht's not work.
So i reinstall it.
Thank's all for advices.... brb in a few thank's again

Comment: RESOLVED : i make an install of software to solved the problem )) 

Thank's all for help.